# chosen-js css styles not loading

Tags: jquery-chosen

I'm having a problem using chosen-js where the styles aren't loading. I'm using webpack, so I'm not sure if there is an additional css file I need to include, but the npm package doesn't seem to have any additional css files.

[image]

It seems like it's just rendering as a normal list, and the styles are not imported.

[image]

So my question is, do I have to import an additional .css file for chosen.js to work (with webpack)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is chosen.css which you need to include.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.3/chosen.min.css

This file is also present in the npm package.

Also make sure you have the .png files in scope.

Here is the content of the node_modules/chosen-js

[image]

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for including it with webpack? Right now I just have `import "chosen-js";` in my main javascript file but it's not working

Comment: Figured it out, i need to have an additional `import "chosen-js/chosen.css"` and `import "chosen-js/chosen-sprite.png"`